# nhibernate transform an entity from one type to the other: how to handle collections?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have a very similar situation to what's described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001877/is-it-ever-valid-to-convert-an-object-from-a-base-class-to-a-subclass):
`Engineer` and `Manager` both inherit from `Contact`, and `Engineer` can be promoted (or demoted, depending on your perspective) to `Manager`.

difference is- I log all orders submitted by a contact.
meaning- my `Contact` class has a `IList<Order> Orders` property, which can consist of 100,000s of orders. (before you ask- obviously this property isn't ever loaded into memory, it's just the opposite end of the `Contact OrderSubmitter` property of `Order`).

I like the idea of a 'copy constructor' of sort, suggested by @Jamie Ide.
the question is- can I change the referemce of the `Order` objects without loading them to memory?

**[EDIT]**
yes, I can- using [HQL update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390561/nhibernate-update-single-field-without-loading-entity/3390601#3390601).
However, this creates a different problem- I'm trying to create an entity and have other entities referencing it in the same transaction. meaning:

```
Manager manager = new Manager(engineer);
session.Save(manager);
session.CreateQuery("update Order set OrderSubmitter = :manager where OrderSubmitter = :engineer")
  .SetParameter("manager",manager)
  .SetParameter("engineer",engineer)
   .ExecuteUpdate();
session.Transaction.Commit();
```

however- the ExecuteUpdate occurs immidiately, whereas the `Manager` entity is only saved on 'commit'.
This, of course, results in a foreign key exception.
I can get around it by explicitly calling `session.Flush()` right after the `Save(manager)` call, but that doesn't seem very good practice.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, the problem is that ExecuteUpdate() occurs immediately and isn't issued after the new manager is inserted. I think that calling session.Flush() immediately is the right solution. You should also delete the original engineer object in the same transaction.

See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478296/nhibernate-changing-sub-types).

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that your modeling is incorrect.
In OO an object does not change its type.
The Manager/Engineer should be modeled as One-To-One relationship.
You can have a job class as a component property of Employee.
Than when an employee is promoted from engineer to manager, you only have to replace the component. Also - you won't have to update the orders table, as the submitter remains the same. The only difference is its job component