# in object oriented programming what do you mean by object?

Tags: theory

i have some question about programming theory , in object oriented programming what do you mean by object?
thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to explain an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995161/how-to-explain-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

think of it as

**class is

```
 defining a model**
```

and  object is

**"bringing it to life "**

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is just an abstraction of an entity.

If it is too hard to understand it, how about the following:

> Object is just an instance of something, with some properties to
>   **describe** it, and some actions/functions to **manipulate** it.

For example, you can see an basketball as an object, and it may look like:

```
basketball: {
    // Properties to describe this ball!
    int radius,
    string color,
    decimal price,
    bool isItNew,
    bool isItFullyPumped,
    ....
    // Actions to act on this ball!
    void roll()
    void bounce()
    void flying()
    ...
}
```

Of course, how to **abstract** a real life basketball to an programming object, is your choice and case-dependent, but you get the point of what is an object